# How to edit uploaded multiple file input partially?

Tags: php, file-upload, edit, jquery-filer

I want to edit already uploaded multiple files.
I use [jquery plugin](https://gerardbalaoro.github.io/jQuery.filer/) to upload files.

1. I created a form and used jquery filer plugin to upload multiple files.
2. Added php code in backend to upload them to server and the urls into array saved in database.
3. I can preload the uploaded files to jquery filer with file option.
4. I can delete the uploaded file with ondelete option.

Now I want to delete some files add upload some files and then create a new array containing the new set of files to save in database.

I am a beginner.  I don't have any ideas and I already searched whole of the internet.

Comment: Are you asking us how to modify your code without us knowing or seeing it?

Comment: I assume you already have an array of the initially uploaded files, so why not just remove the items you delete from that array and push any newly uploaded items to the same array? This question is a bit broad, as well. Generally, we like to see some code and have the problem narrowed down as much as possible. Asking "How do I do X" will usually get you a bunch of negative responses from people, so try to provide as much detail as you can.